# How to access parent from control from inner from group in nested reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am using reactive forms with DTO. In this we have some complex nested structure.

So when we design html,In one section some fields from one form & some fields from another.

For ex.

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
    'access_code':['', Validators.required],
    'patinet': fb.group({
        'fullname': ['', Validators.required],
        'gender': [],
        'address': fb.group({
            'street': [''],
            'houseNumber': [''],
            'postalCode': ['']
        })
    })
});

<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fullname">Order</label>
    <input type="text" id="order" formControlName="order" class="form-control">
  </div>       
  <div formGroupName="patient">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="street">Fullname</label>
      <input type="text" id="fullname" value="street" formControlName="fullname" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="street">AccessCode</label>
        <input type="text" id="access_code" value="access_code" formControlName="access_code" class="form-control">
      </div>
    <div formGroupName="address">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="street">street</label>
        <input type="text" id="street" value="street" formControlName="street" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="houseNumber">houseNumber</label>
        <input type="text" id="houseNumber" value="houseNumber" formControlName="houseNumber" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postalCode">postalCode</label>
        <input type="text" id="postalCode" value="postalCode" formControlName="postalCode" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see i have **access_code** field inside patient-form section but this field belong to parent-form.

I have this kind of structure in which one section in design contains fields from different form-group.

I want to know is there any way to define that specific from belong to specific(parent-form in this case) form-group?

Comment: So what is the reason to have different structure in form model thatn in HTML markup?

Comment: I have complex structure then this. Design should be customer friendly & dto are designed to work better in back-end. So this is just example. In real it will be quite different.

Comment: And that is exaclty the reason why form model is different than DTO. So required approach is in contradiction to reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

So what is the reason to have different structure in form model than in HTML markup? If this is because of DTO than your approach is wrong. Form model does not have to reflect DTOs model (like it would normally do in model driven forms) as you will be able to map between form model and DTO in post processing. In my opinion, that is main reason it exists - to detach form from data model.

Form model should be reflected in HTML.

EDIT:
Anyway, if you are want to go that way, you can always bind form control directly - just for that controll - instead of using form group/names using `[formControl]` and `FormGroup#get`. More or less it would be like

```
<input [formControl]=this.myForm.get('access_key;');/>
```

If you don't have reference to top level form group, you can use https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#parent to traverse to it.

Comment: It's my client's requirement that to create form-group similar to dto. I know my approach is not ideal but i'd like to know about possibility to use parent form's control in child from control.

Comment: I am not sure why client cares about form model at all.

Comment: I am not understanding that why do we have to discuss about my requirements at all.

Comment: Edited. You can bind directly instead of using names.

Comment: Can you give me an example. How to use form -group/names in another form

Comment: You don't. You bind `input` directly to `controll` instance. You can get any controll from form group.

Comment: How will it work in my case? Like i said i want to use parent's control in child

Comment: You just get controll from parent form and bind it to input.